# Variables with angle brackets in CMake scripts

Tags: cmake

I noticed that CMake can use variables not only in `${VAR_NAME}` syntax, but also in `<VAR_NAME>` syntax. For example, following code:

```
IF(NOT CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE)
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE
    "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER>  <FLAGS> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>  -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
ENDIF(NOT CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE)
```

was found in CMake modules folder in script named `CMakeCXXInformation.cmake`.

I didn't find any explanation about syntax using angle brackets in the documentation. Has someone used such syntax who can explain its meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular CMake variables can be dereferenced with usual `${FOO}` syntax. These dereferences occur during CMake's running.

At some point, CMake introduced [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) which have form of `$<FOO>`. From the CMake perspective, such expressions are plain strings. However, they get substituted during the buildsystem-generation phase (for instance, when you run `make` or `ninja`).

Finally, there are `<FOO>` expressions. These are also plain strings and are mostly used in the internal CMake code as substitutes that later get replaced with `string(REPLACE ...)` command. For instance, such expressions are used extensively when adding support for new language in CMake, see `share/cmake/Modules/CMakeAddNewLanguage.txt` for more info on this.

The documentation for [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) commands mention some `<FOO>` styled variables. `<SOURCE_DIR>` and `<BINARY_DIR>` are obviosly get replaced with real source and build directories for a given external project (not `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` and `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` of the project that called `ExternalProject_*()`), but I wasn't able to find a full list of available substitutions for this set of commands.

Comment: But what the difference? Why they use ${VAR} and <VAR> syntax internally?

Comment: `<VAR>` in this case is plain string. It's not part of CMake language. I suppose, CMake devs intentionally made them different to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hmm, so to be 100% clear, `<VAR>` doesn't have any meaning other than to maybe be replaced later by some kind of string parsing function? It seems like this is the case but I don't quite understand why cmake even used these placeholder values. If you're curious, what brought me here is there's a line of code that uses `<BINARY_DIR>` in a piece of code I inherited, I thought it was a placeholder too, but apparently it is given a value somehow...? It comes back with a real path even though I thought only `${BINARY_DIR}` can be used to get a variable's value.

Comment: This is probably kind of a weird theory, but the code in question provides command line arguments to cmake itself; it's a cmake script that runs cmake; does cmake itself count as an uh... language to cmake? EDIT: Looks like they have special meaning to [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)

Comment: I notice that all of the examples on that page are of the form `$<var>`, but I was wondering more about the cases where there is no dollar sign, as in, just `<var>`. My testing seems to show that this is something that might be specific to ExternalProject_Add, but I am not sure who evaluates these expressions, the external project being added, or the project that's adding the external project.

Comment: I'm still unclear on this as I seem to be in the exact situation as @jrh. And even here [on the 
 ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#:~:text=COMMAND%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BCMAKE_COMMAND%7D%20--build%20%3CBINARY_DIR%3E%20--config%20%24%3CCONFIG%3E) page both <BINARY_DIR> and <$CONFIG> are used?
Why would someone use the bare angle brackets in ExternalProject commands?